# Angular Material dataSource filter with array of string

Tags: angular-material, material-table, angular-material-table

I am using Material table in my Angular project.

There is a provision to filter string and it working perfectly

```js
myData: UserData[]; // Imagine its initialized
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(myData);

applyFilter(filterValue: string)
{
  this.dataSource.filter = filterValue
}
```

Now, I want to filter with array of strings, but it's not working.

```js
myData: UserData[]; // Imagine its initialized
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(myData);

applyFilter(filteredValues: string[])
{
  this.dataSource.filteredData = filteredValues
}
```

Getting below error

> Type 'String[]' is not assignable to type 'UserData[]'.
> Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'UserData'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to filter from datasource of type String[], you have to specify a filterpredicate.

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: String, filter: string) => {
    return data.includes(filter);
};
```

This now return all the string that includes the 'filterValue'.